# Каталог продукции без плагинов

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, очень интересует вопрос, не находил похожих тут. Можно ли на Wordpress организовать каталог продукции без использования плагинов? Шаблон у меня свой, а переписывать стили для плагина не знаю как, да и не охота заморачиваться. Тонну статей перерыл, везде поголовно используют плагины, неужели нельзя простыми записями на страницу вывести несколько товаров, а при нажатии, к примеру на кнопку "подробнее", открывалась бы страница-шаблон для этой записи?

Comment: Можно. Только это будет не каталог продукции в полном понимании этого термина а обычный сайт визитка со статьями, каждая из которых будет страницей с товаром.

Comment: Это нормально, мне как раз такое и нужно, без поиска, фильтров и прочего.

Comment: ну так и делайте простые страницы с товарами а потом какую нибудь табличку основную со ссылками на эти страницы в виде каталога да и все дела

Comment: Так вот проблема что не до конца понятно как реализовать это через админку, какой цикл прописать, чтобы посты в каталоге выводились в 2 столбца, и каждый по кнопке открывался в новом окне?

Comment: ну если там тысяча товаров то такой подход не очень конечно, а если десять и больше не будет то это самый простой вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего стандартный тип записей вам еще понадобится, поэтому:

1. Вам необходимо зарегистрировать новый тип записей, я говорю о [CPT (Сustom Post Types)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
2. Создаете шаблон страницы для вывода всех товаров (если нужно).
3. Создаете шаблон для вывода записи.
4. Возможно Вам еще понадобится несколько зарегистрированых Taxonomy, для вывода категорий и меток.

Ну, а дальше на Ваше усмотрение. Успехов!

Пример регистрации CPT

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
            'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

Comment: Без плагинов можно, но тогда нужно разбираться и немного больше потратите время. Можно сделать с минимальным кол-вом плагинов, что возможно будет более правильным, а вот полностью все делать на плагинах не стоит потому, что будет большая нагрузка на сайт. Да и не найдете Вы решение под себя. Поэтому используйте минимальный набор и самое необходимое.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создавать страницы с товарами, каждый товар как отдельная страница, и они будут дочерними страницами по отношению к странице со списком товаров, для которой нужно будет создать отдельный шаблон и там просто циклом из выводить.
Вот так можно получить дочерние страницы например:

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
));
```

Можно ещё в админке добавить для страниц товаров дополнительные поля, тогда их удобно выводить например так `<?=$pages[$i]->weight;?>`. 
Ну и для самих страниц товаров можно создать отдельный шаблон и так же выводить дополнительные поля.

Comment: Можно, но решение своеобразное. Если разобрать любой из плагинов, который позволяет реализовать магазин или каталог, то ни один из них такой подход не использует. Если не прав - ткните пальцем. Для общего развития не помешает